# Update every instance in a queryset with a count atomically

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to update a field of a queryset atomically. I have something like this:

```
counter = 0
for row in myQuerySet:
  row.myField = counter
  counter = counter + 1
  row.save()
```

That works, but I want to do this atomically, because I have hundreds of registers and it is a waste of time. I need something like this:

```
counter = 0
myQuerySet.update(myField=(counter+=1))
```

But that does not work. What is the correct sintax for this?

Comment: An update statement creates a single SQL query and if you are using a value which is not part of the table (i.e. it is not a field) it will be treated as constant and in that case all rows will be updated with same value.

Comment: `F()` objects can help update a field based on an existing field value, but I can't think of a way to update a field based on an incrementing external value.

Comment: @Sayse I have a lot of registers with a "step_number" integer field. This field can be changed manually and you can obtain an incremental sequence with gaps, for example, if you have 5 registers, their step_numbers can be 1,2,3,8,9. But I want to renumber that to obtain a 1,2,3,4,5 sequence. That is the purpose of the counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That works, but I want to do this atomically […]

Often, the answer is to use the [`QuerySet.update` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update). That works when you want to do the same thing – or something that doesn't need to change dynamically – to all the instances in a queryset.

Since the operation you want to perform appears to need a dynamic change to each instance in turn, you can instead use the [`select_for_update` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update).

```python
from django.db import transaction

dolors = LoremIpsum.objects.select_for_update().filter(dolor=True)

with transaction.atomic():
    counter = 0
    for lorem_ipsum in dolors:
        lorem_ipsum.amet = counter
        counter += 1
        lorem_ipsum.save()
```

The [documentation for `select_for_update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) says this does what you want:

> All matched entries will be locked until the end of the transaction block, meaning that other transactions will be prevented from changing or acquiring locks on them.

Because the queryset causes the items to be “locked until the end of the transaction block”, you need to perform your operations inside a transaction block using `transaction.atomic` as above.

Comment: That's it! There is missing the "objects" part before the select_for_update and I will only add that is necessary to add "with transaction.atomic()" (from django.db import transaction) because select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.