# Can Django F function bulk update random number?

Tags: django, django-orm

I want to update field:`number` with 'current number + random number' :

Here is my code, I have 650 games in database,and it needs almost 8 seconds to update it.

```
objs = Game.objects.all()
for obj in objs:
    Game.objects.filter(name=obj.name).update(number=F('number') + random.randint(1,100))
```

If I use F function, the the code below will have a problem :
the `random.randint(1,100)` is the same for all rows ,
Can I randomly use different numbers with  F funciton? Or Is there some method by which I can speed up my query ??

```
Game.objects.all().update(number=F('number') + random.randint(1,100))
```

Comment: Probably would be better to do it in raw sql at that point, no easy way to do it in django orm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update every instance in a queryset with a count atomically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909357/update-every-instance-in-a-queryset-with-a-count-atomically)

Comment: Not a direct duplicate but I'd imagine the solution is the same

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you can generate random number firstly at step one and then assign them to number field of Game model,
Like this :

```
objs = Game.objects.all()
for obj in objs:
    random_number = random.randint(1,100)
    obj.number = random_number
    obj.save()
```

Or in a better way,you dont need to iterate through the for loop,just use this :

```
def generate_random(request):
  number = random.randint(1,100)
  return number

def your_view(request):

  objs = Game.objects.all()
  objs.update(number=F('number') + generate_random() )
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first solution works but it hits the database for every object so be warned. The second one still gives every object the same "random" number