# django queryset element can't be changed?

Tags: python, django

```
 def cumulate(self, dataset):
    nb = 0
    for i in range(dataset.count()):
        nb += dataset[i]['nb']
        dataset[i]['nb'] = 99
        print(dataset[i]['nb'])
    return dataset
```

why this prints original values instead of printing 99 ?

Comment: Is `dataset` a queryset or is it something else? as written there isn't anything django specific here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to change elements of dataset. dataset is a django queryset. using values method we can use iterate for elements as dictionaries

Comment: Values "Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries" which isn't quite the same thing, I'm still not entirely sure what it is you're trying to do

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Update every instance in a queryset with a count atomically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40909357/1324033)

Comment: whatever what I am trying to do why 99 can't be assigned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Django is doing a separate query to fetch each individual `dataset[i]`, and a final query when `dataset` is evaluated.

The solution is to to force the queryset to be evaluated by converting it to a list. You'll have to use `len()` instead of `count()`.

```
def cumulate(self, dataset):
    dataset = list(dataset)
    nb = 0
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        nb += dataset[i]['nb']
        dataset[i]['nb'] = 99
        print(dataset[i]['nb'])
    return dataset
```

It would be more pythonic to iterate over the queryset instead of looping over the range. In this case, looping over the queryset will cause it to be evaluated, and I don't think you'll have to convert it to a list.

```
def cumulate(self, dataset):
    nb = 0
    for d in dataset:
        nb += d['nb']
        d['nb'] = 99
        print(d['nb'])
    return dataset
```